# How to get the position of the item in list to remove using gesture action in gesture overlayview

Tags: java, android

MainActivity.java

```
   public class MainActivity extends ListActivity implements OnGesturePerformedListener {



   static SQLiteDatabase db;

   public static String TABEl_CREATE="CONTACTS";
   public static String DATA_BASE_TABLE_CREATE = "create table if not exists " +TABEl_CREATE+ "(Name text not null ,Number number unique not null)";

   GestureLibrary lib;
   private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

   ListView lv;

       @Override
       public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       db = openOrCreateDatabase("contacts", MODE_PRIVATE, null);
       db.execSQL(DATA_BASE_TABLE_CREATE);

       lv = (ListView) findViewById (android.R.id.list);
       populatelv();


       lib = GestureLibraries.fromRawResource(this, R.raw.gestures);
       if (!lib.load()) {
        finish();
        }

       GestureOverlayView gesture = (GestureOverlayView) 
            findViewById(R.id.gestures);

       gesture.addOnGesturePerformedListener(this);

       }


       private void populatelv() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
       Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT Name FROM " +TABEl_CREATE, null);

       if (c != null ) {
        if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                String Name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Name"));

                results.add( Name  );

          }while (c.moveToNext());

        } 

       }    
       adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getBaseContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,android.R.id.text1,results);
       lv.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

   @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       return true;
       }

   public void onGesturePerformed(GestureOverlayView overlay, Gesture gesture) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ArrayList<Prediction> predictions = lib.recognize(gesture);


    if (predictions.size() > 0)

    {
        String action = predictions.get(0).name;
        if (predictions.get(0).score > 1.0)
        {


            if ("ADD".equals(action)) 
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Adding a contact",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Intent i = new  Intent(MainActivity.this,Database.class);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

            } 

            else 
                if ("delete".equals(action))
             {


                Toast.makeText(this, "Removing a contact",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



                    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub





                      // Here,how can i get the position of the specific listitem where gesture action took place..?




        // String str = lv.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();

        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // String delete = "delete from contacts where Name = '"+str+"'";
        //db.execSQL(delete);
        //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Deleted", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }

                    }) ;

            }

            else if ("refresh".equals(action))
            {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Reloading contacts",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

     }

        }

       }

          }
```

Database.java

```
     public class Database extends Activity {

   Button add;
   EditText name,number;
   SQLiteDatabase db;



   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.database);

db= MainActivity.db;
db = openOrCreateDatabase("contacts", MODE_PRIVATE, null);



        add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

        add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String nval,nbval;

        nval = name.getText().toString();
        nbval = number.getText().toString();

        if(nval.length()>0 && nbval.length()>0)
        {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put("Name", nval);
            cv.put("Number", nbval);



            db.insert("CONTACTS","title", cv);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inserted  sucessfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

        }

        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill all fields!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }


    }
 });



    }

    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
Intent intent=new Intent(Database.this,MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
 startActivity(intent);     


    };

        }
```

Here,i'm trying to display contacts in listview by retrieving from database which is done by Database.java.I'm able add the contacts into database using gesture but when i tried to delete the specific contact from list using gesture,i can't able to do..I'm new to development of android applications..please suggest me..here is my code.

Comment: why are you trying to assign OnItemClickListener in Delete gesture action? FYI, it can't be executed.

Comment: in the process of finding the best one,i used OnItemClickListener also..but as you said i couldn't do that.please guide me how to do it in a proper manner.Thanks in advance.